# How to sum amounts according their ID-s and add the results to a new column on an existing table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table (the table below) that grow fast has more than 4 million rows

This the table i am taking about:

```
#   Name    Type       Collation    Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
 1  user_id int(11)         No  None         Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 2  amount  decimal(16,8)           No  None         Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 3  aff int(11)         No  0        Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 4  jackpot int(11)         No  0        Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 5  paidout int(11)         No  0        Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 6  type    int(11)         No  0        Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 7  created timestamp           No  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP        Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
```

I run a query  to SUM amounts by user_id and i get the results

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(amount) 
FROM trans
group by user_id;
```

My question is how can i add these results (SUM-s)to another existing table i have the same user ids and save these SUM-s there

the existing table i have has this structure

```
#   Name    Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
 1  id  int(4)          No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT   Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values  Primary Primary  Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 2  balance int(11)         No  None         Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 3  ads varchar(60) latin1_swedish_ci       No  None         Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 4  ip  varchar(85) latin1_swedish_ci       No           Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 5  hash    varchar(150)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None         Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 6  email   varchar(150)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None         Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 7  aff int(11)         No  0        Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 8  with    int(11)         No  0        Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 9  timestamp   bigint(20)      UNSIGNED    No  0        Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
```

I would prefer to place the sums on a new column after the id column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
alter table table2 add column thesum decimal(16, 8);

update table2 t2
    set thesum = (select sum(amount) from table1 t1 where t2.user_id = t1.user_id)
```

Now, there are certain issues with this.  When the values change in the first table, they do not change in the second table.  To make that happen, you need to use a trigger to re-adjust the values.

Often, it is recommended to use views for such a process.  However, that is not particularly efficient.  My guess is that you want to summarize the values for performance reasons.  If so, just be careful about keeping the values consistent.

EDIT:

To add in the sum, just do:

```
update table2 t2
    set thesum = thesum + coalesce((select sum(amount) from table1 t1 where t2.user_id = t1.user_id), 0);
```

Comment: The reason i need to do this is because i need to delete the big table periodically because it slows down too much my server and to keep the updated balances on the other table

Comment: @user38935 . . . There may be other ways to improve performance on the larger table, such as using partitions.  However, that is an answer to another question.  If you want to keep all the history and get decent performance, ask another question.

Comment: The query worked fine the first time, but now if i empty the table nr1  and after a while new rows has been generated and i need to add the new Sum to the sum on column on the table nr2 and (SUM the to SUM-s , the new Sum generated orm table Nr1 and the old Sum on table nr2)

Comment: Now i tested it with the big table with and the query seems to block the server , I tested many times restarting the server but everytime the server blocks and php admin becomes unresponsive

Comment: I asked a new question about improving the perormance of this table http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24340696/collapse-large-database-table-to-one-row-per-user