# Collapse large database table to one row per user

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am running a casino (not real money) website that everytime a user plays a row is generated on a table "trans" on my database that make this database grow soo much that is crashing my server

This is the table structure

```
    Name        Type            Collation   Attributes          Null    Default     Extra       Action
 1  user_id     int(11)         No          None                Change  Change      Drop Drop    Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 2  amount      decimal(16,8)   No          None                Change  Change      Drop Drop    Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 3  aff         int(11)         No          0                   Change  Change      Drop Drop    Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 4  jackpot     int(11)         No          0                   Change  Change      Drop Drop    Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 5  paidout     int(11)         No          0                   Change  Change      Drop Drop    Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 6  type        int(11)         No          0                   Change  Change      Drop Drop    Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 7  created     timestamp       No          CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   Change  Change      Drop Drop    Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
```

This table has abount 4 million rows actually and only 30000 users (user_id )
My question is , is there a way to to collapse the table let say daily and save only one row per user and keep their balances (amount).

I am trying this without success:

update trans

SELECT * FROM  `trans` group by user_id
set amount = (select sum(amount) from trans

Comment: The question is "why is it like it is now"? Can you show the `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` output?

Comment: If this is real money we're talking about, I seriously don't think you'll want to remove any info on transactions.

Comment: It is not real money , What is SHOW CREATE TABLE table output?

Comment: The output of the sql statement `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourTableName` in the mysql client of your choice, i.e. the mysql command line client.

Comment: Table
Create Table
trans
CREATE TABLE `trans` (
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `amount` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL,
 `aff` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `jackpot` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `paidout` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `type` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: Four million rows is not a big table by today's standards.  Consider looking more broadly for a solution.

Comment: 4 million in one month  and it keep growing exponentially

Answer (score 0):

here are some broad steps:

1. create a new summary table.
2. add a trigger on the original table to look up this user and add the amount to his total in the summary table
3. clear out all the old entries on some schedule

or

1. change your application logic to do an update instead of an insert

or

you can write one single GROUP BY style query to add up all the users info and return that instead of all the detail - probably what you are doing is select * which is using up all your memory.. bad

Comment: I do not want to crate a new table i just want to group those millions rows by user_id  and sum their amounts to keep the final balance.

Comment: then write the group by query.